# How to split string without spaces into list of integers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I take a string of integers as input and there are no spaces or any kind of separator:

```
12345
```

Now I want this string to converted into a list of individual digits

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I've tried both

```
numlist = map(int,input().split(""))
```

and

```
numlist = map(int,input().split(""))
```

Both of them give me Empty Separator error. Is there any other function to perform this task?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to use split here:

```
>>> a = "12345"    
>>> map(int, a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Strings are Iterable too

For python 3x:

```
list(map(int, a))
```

Comment: This is what I was looing for. This perfectly served my purpose. My question is marked as duplicate, but in the other question, no answer explains how to split an input as in this answer. Please see to that @Carsten.

Answer (score 5):

Use list_comprehension.

```
>>> s = "12345"
>>> [int(i) for i in s]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Love this. So expressive.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are brilliant. Here is an approach using regex

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '12345'
>>> re.findall(r'\d',s)
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Ref - [Docs on Regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

**Why use regex for everything?**

Answer (score -3):

You also can use

```
>>> range(1,6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: That doesn't convert from a string though...

Comment: Where it is taking the string...

Comment: I want to take an input

Comment: Oh, yes. you right, but if so it can be used as work around