# Converting string to an int array using map

Tags: python, python-3.x

Reading [Python - converting a string of numbers into a list of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334374/python-converting-a-string-of-numbers-into-a-list-of-int) I'm attempting to convert string '011101111111110' to an array of ints : [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]

Here is my code :

```
mystr = '011101111111110'
list(map(int, mystr.split('')))
```

But returns error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-9b0dca2f0819> in <module>()
      1 mystr = '011101111111110'
----> 2 list(map(int, mystr.split('')))

ValueError: empty separator
```

How to split the string that has an empty splitting separator and convert result to an int array ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split string without spaces into list of integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409273/how-to-split-string-without-spaces-into-list-of-integers-in-python)

Comment: `list(map(int, '011101111111110'))` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list(map(int, list(mystr)))
```

Should do the job. You can't split on an empty string, but Python supports casting `str` to `list` as a built-in. I wouldn't use `map` for situations like these though, but instead use a list comprehension:

```
[int(x) for x in mystr]
```

Comment: you don't even have to convert to a list first. `mystr` is already iterable. So: `list(map(int, mystr))`

Comment: nice, I was about to post an answer with the list comprehension, but with your edit, I'll just upvote your answer instead!

Comment: Given @MarcusMüller's comment why do you not correct your answer to `list(map(int, mystr))`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Since that would invalidate the comment.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's a concern for meta. The comment is prominent and I prefer not editing my answer now. Feel free to add a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split your string as it is already iterable. For instance:

```py
mystr = '011101111111110'
result = list(map(int, mystr))

print(result) # will print [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: @DavidG:  It doesn't include the unnecessary `list(mystr)` which is a major improvement.  The other answer acts as if strings are not iterable.