# convert string of numbers into list of integers in python

Tags: python, list

I have a string 12345678 and I want to convert it into a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] in python.

I tried this method :
[image: I tried this method]

Comment: It seems like the problem in your code is that you are splitting on commas but you didn't enter the numbers like this: `"1,2,3,4"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split string without spaces into list of integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409273/how-to-split-string-without-spaces-into-list-of-integers-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
list(map(int, '12345678'))  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
[int(x) for x in '12345678']  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: `map(int, '12345678')` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want without loop or map, You can try:

```
final_=[]
def recursive(string1):
    if not string1:
        return 0
    else:
        final_.append(int(string1[0]))
        return recursive(string1[1:])
recursive('12345678')
print(final_)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```