# Is there a simple way to output a list within a list in python? like this [[0,1], [2,3]]

Tags: python, string, slice, nested-lists

I solved the logical part of the following exercise, but can't find a simple solution to output in the required format. It looks like a list within a list to me.

Problem description:

> Write a program that will take a string of digits and give you all the
>   possible consecutive slices of length n in that string.
>
> Raise an error if n is larger than the length of the string.
>
> Examples For example, the string "01234" has the following 2-digit
>   slices:
>
> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
>
> The same string has the following 4-digit slices:
>
> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

This is my code which is working fine except the way it returns the answer is different so can't submit it.

```
digits = "01234"
n = 4
result = [None]*(len(digits)-n+1) #create a list with required size
for x in range(0, len(digits)-n+1):
    result[x] = digits[x:n]
    n += 1
print(result)
```

This code prints `['0123', '1234']`, which is the correct answer but I want it in this format: `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

(edit) adding this line solved my problem suggested by mkrieger1, thanks
This is the final code:

    `def series_slices(digits, n):
        digits = [int(x) for x in digits]
        result = []
        for x in range(0, len(digits)-n+1):
            result.append(list(digits[x:n]))
            n += 1
        return result`

Comment: are you looking for `json.dump`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Concerning your problem, at what point exactly does the value of your variables not have the desired state? In other words, extract a [mcve]! As a note, Python knows two ways to "print" an object, one is using the conversion to a string and the other is via `repr()` and each class' implementation thereof. Check the docs to understand how your code works. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You need to convert the input string to a list of integers at the beginning: `digits = [int(x) for x in digits]`. The rest of the code should then work unchanged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split string without spaces into list of integers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409273/how-to-split-string-without-spaces-into-list-of-integers-in-python)

Comment: @mkrieger1 i am trying what you suggested, but i am thinking, converting the input string into int() would take away the leading zero in the input string. wouldn't it.?

Comment: THat's not "converting the input string into int()" but into a list of integers.

Comment: No, it wouldn't, because it doesn't convert the string to a single integer at once, but converts the individual characters.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks friend, digits = [int(x) for x in digits] this line solved my problem. & this inline loop syntax is cool, i need to master it

Answer (score 1):

Just use `list` on your strings:

```
list('0123')
```

returns

```
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

And convert it to integers (thanks mkrieger, I hadn't read the question carefully enough:

You can use `map`, that will iterate on the characters of your string and return an integer for each one, then make a list out of the map object:

```
list(map(int, '0123'))
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

or use a list comprehension:

```
[int(digit) for digit in '0123'] 
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

More generally, applying `list` to anything iterable will return a list of its items.

Comment: `list('0123')` is `['0', '1', '2', '3']`. Need to convert to integers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You c an do this with a list comprehension. First level goes through the sizes and second level takes the slices for that size:

```
digits = "01234"
r=[list(digits[start:][:size+1]) for size in range(len(digits)) for start in range(len(digits)-size)]
print(r)

# [['0'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], 
#  ['0', '1'], ['1', '2'], ['2', '3'], ['3', '4'], 
#  ['0', '1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'],['2', '3', '4'], 
#  ['0', '1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
#  ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

Answer (score -1):

change your code to
`result = []`
and `result.append(list(digits[x:n]))` in line 3 and line 5.